# configure spring security and test api postman

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, postman

Iam working in springboot application and iam trying to save the data in database, code is executing properly and not getting any error during execution but when iam trying to post the url in postman iam getting status: 401 unauthorized

any quick suggestion

```
        public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
            @Autowired
            UsersService userService;
            @Autowired
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
            
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                http.csrf().disable() //TODO implementer csrf
                    .cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/ add-users").permitAll()
                    .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            }
          @Service
        public class UsersService implements UserDetailsService{
            @Autowired
            UsersRepository repo;
           // @Autowired
           // private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
            
            public Users save(Users u) {
                
                String encodpass=new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(u.getPassword());
                String confpass=new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(u.getConfirmepass());
                u.setConfirmepass(confpass);
                u.setPassword(encodpass);
                u.setLock(false);
                u.setEnable(true);
                return repo.save(u);
            }
           @RestController
        public class UsersController {
            @Autowired
            private UsersService service;
            
            @PostMapping("/add-users")
            public Users add(@RequestBody Users u) {
                
                return service.save(u);
            }`
```

Comment: please google on how to enable spring security debug logs and post them here. Learn how to debug your application. Also `when iam trying to post the url in postman iam getting status: 401 unauthorized` what url? steps to reproduce, debug logs, small running example? if you want serious help, then please ask a serious question with all information

Comment: I still have to login even though I specified permitAll in spring security

Comment: where are your debug logs? where is your request, request log etc. Small reproducible example? downvoted... missing debugging information

Answer (score 0):

First  of all
remove this space and retest :

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/ add-users").permitAll()
```

to

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/add-users").permitAll()
```

Comment: I did that but the always error 401, the problem even if I made a request with GET to http://localhost:9090/ i get error 401

Comment: I specified .antMatchers("/").permitAll(), but if i don't authenticate i get 401 !

Comment: Can you provide us with additional info ?

Comment: I still have to login even though I specified permitAll in spring security